# Javascript penetration

Tags: javascript, html

Working on developing a web application, and there needs to be some graceful fallback for browsers without javascript.  However are there were any statistics around how many  people (real people, not indexing robots) run their browsers without javascript on (or use a browser with no javascript).

Comment: I haven't even seen stats on that in a couple of years, would be willing to bet its less than 1% now.  IMHO writing server side code to protect against any security holes that could be exploited by turning off javascript (bypassing validation, etc) is mandatory...writing a whole extra site for those with no javascript may have been worthwhile in the late 90s but its a waste of time now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How many people disable JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121108/how-many-people-disable-javascript) :-p

Comment: Have a look at "unobtrusive javascript." Supported pretty well in VS2010/MVC3, not sure about other platforms.

Comment: You don't have to write "a whole extra site" to support (for example) screen readers that don't run javascript e.g. for blind or low-vision users. Start with standard forms and controls, plain GET and POST (no ajax) and then *enhance* it with javascript. Don't think of it as "fallback".

Comment: Using MVC with Jquery for unobtrusive javascript already(isAjaxRequst is your friend).... BTW  has anyone tried to go to facebook without javascript on.

Comment: If they don't have JS, they don't deserve to view your site....

Comment: OMFG. -1 to @Greg McNulty for that. I met my friend Doug many years ago on a BBS and found out only much later that he's blind. He's perfectly capable of using a computer and The Web, but you'd exclude him from your site because his screen reader doesn't run javascript. That means he won't be spending his (considerable) money on your product, or that you won't hire him because he can't use your company's internal web app (grounds for a discrimination lawsuit). I simply *do not* understand this attitude of exclusion.

Comment: Stephen P, I apologize for the attitude of exclusion. My intent was based on the information in the question, or lack of information. The question is open to all sorts of assumptions, I was using the most frequent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As David Lively commented, search for "unobtrusive javascript" as well as "progressive enhancement".  Ignore the old "graceful degradation" articles.

If you start by making a fancy "web 2.0" page then try to gracefully fall back if there's no javascript you'll have a much harder time than if you start with a plain page that works for everyone and then enhance it by using javascript when it's available.

It *can* be done (it's true, I swear, I've done it) regardless of what some people think. It's more than zero effort but it's **not** doing everything twice.

An example from my work is a group membership page. People available are listed on the left, current group members on the right. There's a checkbox next to each name and buttons for "Add To Group" and "Remove From Group".  You can check as many boxes as you want and add or remove group members. This works as a plain HTML form with no javascript required, *however* when the javascript runs all the checkboxes and the two buttons are removed, and the two lists become draggable and droppable. You can move people in and out of the group easily just by dragging them around and hit the single "Save" button when finished.

My point being, and as a roundabout answer to your question, you shouldn't *care* what kind of penetration javascript has in the (your) market.

There will always be some people that disable javascript until they decide they trust your site. These are often some of the most technically savvy people and you may not want to exclude them from your market/audience.

People using screen readers or braille terminals also (still) don't have javascript support although the day may come when they do. In the mean time, do you want to exclude that population from your application?  In my case, I'm *mandated* by the Americans with Disabilities Act (ADA) to support them (I would anyway) and not doing so can lead to discrimination lawsuits.  kekekela's "its a waste of time now" is simply not an acceptable answer for me.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp is one such set of stats.  I don't think there is any one place you can get a definitive number. It's a constantly moving target anyway, but this set of stats is as good as any.

scroll down a bit to see javascript support.

*A good portion of my answer was deleted because, well, it was dumb.*

Comment: It is worth pointing out that those stats are entirely useless as they are representative of the self selected group of people who think that W3Schools is a good resource (not a fair sample of the audience of most websites). Also, if your site is hostile to non-JS users, then you are going to be lowering the proportion of non-JS visitors you have — thus making it look like it isn't worth supporting them.

Comment: Good point.  Personally, out team relies on the Googla Analytics results, although I'm rapidly tending to think of them as too "Big Brother".  The trade off is we do know about our visitors, so we can gear our site toward them.

Comment: Last time I checked, Google Analytics required that the browser have JavaScript enabled in order to track the hit.

Comment: Duh.  You're right.  So does Bing as far as I know.  Deleting that from my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I would create hidden variable with a value of zero, and a piece of Javascript that sets a that field to 1. If the page has a form, the variable would be sent back and counted. If the page doesn't have a form, you could use some AJAX to send back the variable. On your server you could compare the number of pages requested versus the number of 1's that you received for a page.

If your users don't have javascript enabled, forms would return that hidden variable as zero, and pages without forms would not return the variable at all. Still, you would increment the number of views for that page.

If your user do have js enabled, you would increment both the number of views and the number of viewers with javascript.